# Is there anything missing in the for-loop causing the pounds to not be calculated, and display to look junky? output screenshot included

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Problem:
Write a program that creates a conversion table from kilograms to pounds. The program should prompt the user for the starting point of the table in kilograms and list ten entries in increments of one kilogram. The conversion factor is 1 kilogram is equal to 2.2 pounds.

I need to use a for-loop for this program. I tested with inputs 20, 21, 22.

My output is all messed up, the 20 is over the kilograms column when it should be below. The last input, 22,  is ending the program when it should let me enter all numbers between 20 and 30 before it ends. The column pounds is not being calculated. Is there something I'm missing?

The output link is

[image: output]

```
*/import java.util.Scanner;

public class kgToLbs1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        final double LB_PER_KG = 2.2;


        //Algorithm
        //Open keyboard for input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user for beginning value and assign to begVal
        System.out.println("Enter beginning value ===>  ");
        int begVal = input.nextInt();

        //Print conversion table headings
        System.out.println("Kilograms           Pounds");
        int kg = input.nextInt();
        double lb = input.nextDouble();
        
        //endVal = begVal + 9 
        int endValue = begVal + 9;


        for (int i = 20; i <= 30; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d%.2f\n", i , (i * LB_PER_KG));
        }
        //Print conversion table footer 
        System.out.println("End");

        //Close terminal
```

Comment: If you want the 20 to be input after the table header, then why did you put `input.nextInt()` before the header print line?

Comment: Also, can you explain what `"%d%.2f` does?

Comment: Everything is calculated correctly - you just forgot to put spaces between the values. Try `System.out.printf("%d     %.2f\n", i , (i * LB_PER_KG));`.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. I meant print decimal integer, %d, and print float number with 2 digits after the decimal point %.2f

Comment: Right, and it does that, but there is no space there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it should let me enter all numbers between 20 and 30

No, that's not what the instructions say. It says prompt for any starting value, then increment up by one for the next ten values. In other words, print only, not prompt for input

> the 20 is over the kilograms column when it should be below

There is a 20 below. There just isn't a space after it because the printf didn't include a space

> The column pounds is not being calculated

It is. `2044.00` is printing `20` (kg) and `44.00` (lbs) without a space

---

I think you're looking for this

```
    final double LB_PER_KG = 2.2;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter beginning value ===>  ");
    int begVal = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Kilograms\tPounds");
    for (int i = begVal; i <= begVal + 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t%.2f\n", i , (i * LB_PER_KG));
    }
```